# Clearing localStorage when angular application start

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular. I want to clear localStorage when the user browses application first time, so that if browser/tab close and user reopens the application local storage cleared automatically... and the user will be redirected to login component automatically.

Comment: welcome and please check [ask]

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Alternatively, you can also clear separate items in localStorage with

```
localStorage.removeItem('MyItem');
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.... which event should I use to get it clear.... like in ASP.Net we have   `protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) { }` which run once when application starts.